# what is the meaning of " Pressure Containing and Structural Castings"

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Does it mean " Pressure Containing castings and Structural Castings" or  "Pressure Containing-Structural Castings"?

Comment: We need more context, I feel. There is not enough information in the phrase to know either way.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context it really can't be determined.  But my best guess would be that it means the former:

> ***pressure-containing castings*** and ***structural castings***

Is this a section heading in a catalog?

Answer (score 0):

The two terms are alternatives.

Pressure containing castings are designed to hold and confine higher pressures within.

Structural castings merely provide the strcture and cannot (be expected to) withstand high pressures.

The reference here is to the two different classes of products -- both of them.